# Is using short-circuit evaluation to avoid an index out of range exception a bad habit?

Tags: c#, coding-style

This question applies to every programming language that has a short-circuit AND operator, not just C#.

The question is simple - is using short circuit evaluation to avoid an out of range index exception, for example:

```
if ((x > 0) && (bar[x] == foo))
```

or

```
if (((x > 0) && (x < bar.Length)) && (bar[x] == foo))
```

bad coding style? I know I could nest the loops like this:

```
if (x > 0)
{
    if (bar[x] == foo)
    {
    }
}
```

but I find it to be extremely unreadable.

Comment: I love short-circuiting.  I think it's clean, concise and readable.

Comment: This is the definition of subjective.

Comment: @BertEvans Most coding style questions generally are..

Comment: @Daniel That's the point; you seem to be looking for justification of the style you prefer, yet both are valid.  This isn't a question that can be definitively answered on SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say that

```
if ((x > 0) && (bar[x] == foo))
```

is not *bad* coding style. It's probably even *good*. I would definitely prefer it to a nested `if` structure like you describe.

As an aside, I would reduce the number of parentheses you use. Both these are equally correct, at least in C# and most other C-derived languages:

```
if (x > 0 && bar[x] == foo)
if (x > 0 && x < bar.Length && bar[x] == foo)
```

Readers who know the language (you have to assume this at some level) will easily be able to understand the above short-circuit expressions. Those readers would probably object to the nested `if` style, because it takes way more room than is necessary to get the correct behaviour.

Comment: Seconded. In fact, that's especially true when you need an `else` branch, in which case, using a nested `if` structure will really screw up things.

Comment: All right, but how would you reply to the argument that short circuiting is language-specific? That is, if I were to port the code to another language, I couldn't rely on short-circuiting. Just to make it clear, I'm agreeing with you, and I almost always use short-circuiting, but I'd just like to know how you'd reply to that argument.

Comment: Although short-circuiting is a specific language feature, virtually all modern languages I can think of support it, at least as an option. You'd have to dig deep to find a language where it is *not* supported.

Comment: @Daniel When you're porting to another language, these kinds of silly "optimizations" (for readability) is the least of your problems. Also, what you're referring here to as "short circuiting" is actually "Left to right evaluation" / "operator associativity" doing it's thing here.

Comment: @Robll That doesn't really address the main argument though - saying there are bigger problems still doesn't eliminate the problem. And I don't see how this has anything to do with operator associativity: The problem addresses logic operators, like AND or OR, which have no reason to continue processing if their left statement is false or true, respectively. This is the definition of short-circuit evaluation, though you're right, short-circuiting is probably not the correct term to use. I'll change it.

Comment: @Daniel "`saying there are bigger problems still doesn't eliminate the problem`" There **is** (IMO) no problem. The problem you're hypothesizing (porting to a language with different evaluation logic) is almost non-existant and if it exists in some rare case then that language will most likely have more "incompatibilities" so you'ld have to cater for those too. Where does it end? IMHO this is quite in line with "Premature optimization* is the root of all evil". * Though, strictly speaking, we're not talking about optimization other than for readability.

Comment: @RobIII I think you're missing the point. First of all, there IS a problem - porting code that uses short-circuit evaluation to a language that doesn't use short-circuit evaluation is without a doubt a problem. The language you're porting to, or any other problems that might be encountered in the porting, or the chances of a porting like this actually happening, are all irrelevant. Think of it as if you have to port the code to a language that's identical to C# in every way except that it doesn't implement short circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Daniel Then why ask the question in the first place? You answered your own question: never use "short-circuit evaluation" because some other language to which you, someday, *maybe*, would have to port to *could* be incompatible. What point am I missing?

Comment: @Roblll The point of the question was to see how you would reply to the argument, because it seems to be the only one against short circuit evaluation, other than readability. I don't see where I answered my own question, I actually disagree with the argument.

Comment: @Daniel "`because it seems to be the only one against short circuit evaluation, other than readability`" The only argument *that makes sense* (in the real world) **is** (IMO) readability. Pick the method you prefer and stick with it. For the rest I am done reasoning in circles with you. Read [Bert evans comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533010/is-using-short-circuit-evaluation-to-avoid-an-index-out-of-range-exception-a-bad/11533047#comment15247252_11533010).

Comment: @Daniel, totally agree with Robill -- it's completely absurd to *not* use a language feature in C# because *porting* it to some fantasy language might be more difficult.  IMO, you should *never* apply that logic when considering the use of a language feature in *any* langauge. It would be like not using a word in English because someday it might make it more difficult for you to learn the word in French.

Comment: @KirkWoll Offtopic: My username (or nickname if you like) is RobIII (roman numeral 3 :P )

Comment: @KirkWoll I agree with you and Roblll too, though I don't quite understand your analogy.. The problem was that there was some confusion over what I saying - I wasn't condoning or supporting the argument, I just wanted to see how you (specifically Greg, whose answer I accepted) would respond to it. I apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

"Bad coding style" (in this case at least) is what you define it to be. Both are perfectly valid and it's just a matter of taste. It also depends on the number of operations you have in the actual `if()` statement. If there are a lot of comparisons like

```
if ((foo == bar) && (foobar == something) && ((a==b) || (c==d)))
```

it might be beneficial to wrap it in a method like:

```
if (AllMyConditionsAreMet(OnSomeObject))
```

for easier reading/understanding of what is going on.

Comment: By your logic, I could go wild with my code, using goto and the like, not caring for readability or anything.. And it wouldn't be bad coding style, because I wouldn't define it as such.

Comment: Thats why I explicitly said (and I quote): "`in this case at least`"

Comment: What distinguishes this case from any other case where bad coding style might be an issue..? Sorry, I appreciate the answer, but I disagree with the notion that bad coding style should be determined by every individual programmer.

Comment: "`What distinguishes this case from any other case`" is the fact that in this case it doesn't matter. There are clear examples of "bad coding style", the examples you provided us with aren't. The one isn't better / worse than the other. Do we really need to nitpick on this detail? Also, "bad coding style" is not like it's "standardized" or something. In essence, everyone makes up their own mind on what is bad and what isn't. There is no "bad coding style commitee". That doesn't mean common sense should be thrown out the window; that's why programmers usually agree on what's "bad" and what not.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that it can be made a lot cleaner by moving it into its own method:

```
bool IsXBarValid(int x, Bar bar)
{
    return (x > 0) && (bar[x] == foo);
}

// .. then ..
if (IsXBarValid(x, bar))
{
    // etc..
}
```

Obviously I'm not sure how you're implementing it so the method name is a bit whiffy, but generally this is a nice way to clean this sort of code up.

Answer (score 0):

I like simon-whitehead's answer best so far.

If I don't want another method I do:

```
  bool foobar = (x > 0) && (bar[x] == foo);
  if (foobar)
     // etc...
```

I find these styles a lot more readable than either suggestion in the original post.

It helps others who are reading code (porters or not).

They read foobar, and instantly can decide whether this is the part of code they need to inspect in detail, or whether they can skim on.

If on the other hand they see a complicated if statement, potentially with language trickiness inside :-), then it slows them down.